# Solving any 6th degree equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is there a way to transform a 6th degree equation into an easier problem, such as a cubic or a quadratic?

I am talking about any general 6th degree polynomial.

$$ax^6 + bx^5 + cx^4 + dx^3 + ex^2 + fx + g =0 $$

Comment: It depends on the equation. Can you be a little clearer? What is the equation?

Comment: It depends on your 6th degree equation. There is [no](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintic_function#Finding_roots_of_a_quintic_equation) formula for polynomials with a degree higher than $4$.

Comment: I mean any general 6th degree like ax^6 + bx^5 + cx^4 + dx ^3 + ex^2 + fx  + g = 0.

Comment: @jeff, in short: there is no way for a general equation. There are infinitely many cases of 6th degree equation which are reducible to a lesser degree equation in some way or another. You can construct some examples yourself (such as multiplying two cubic equations or three quadratic)

Comment: @JeelShah using radicals and basic operations, but higher degree cases like the fifth and sixth degrees have formulas too.  Not at all simple of course...but they exist.

Comment: Hm, if my answer satisfies your question, then I'm happy I could help.  Though honestly, I do recommend that you learn about Galois theory, which tells you when you can avoid my horrendously directioned answer and get much nicer results.  Also, as a general always, check the rational roots theorem.

Comment: You may find more information [here](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/resolveppn/?PPN=GDZPPN002263807)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a brute force formula for the roots of the general $6$th degree polynomial, the answer lies in [Kampé de Fériet's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kamp%C3%A9_de_F%C3%A9riet_function).  However, I would highly recommend against such a path, as the formulas for $4$th degree polynomials and up are highly difficult to use.

Comment: You know, I'm having strange difficulty finding any good resources on this subject.

Answer (score 3):

There is no general solution by extraction of roots for polynomial equations of degree 5 or higher. What that is, there is no analog to the quadratic, cubic, quartic formulas polynomial equations with degree at 5 or higher. The general result is known as the [Abel-Ruffini theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/Abel-Ruffini_theorem). An expositions of Abel's original proof can be found [here](http://fermatslasttheorem.blogspot.com/2008/10/abels-impossibility-proof.html).

I do not know if there is a closed-form formula in terms of non-elementary functions that gives the roots of an arbitrary-degree polynomial, but the the standard response in algebra or pre-calculus class is that there is no formula for solving equations polynomial equations of degree higher than 4.

Comment: To answer your doubt about the latter half of your answer, there is the Lagrange inversion theorem, which reduces down into a closed form...sometimes, for some degrees.  Though, if you've seen how much more difficult the cubic formula is compared to the quadratic formula, I will tell you the quartic formula is twice as complicated, the quintic trice as complicated as the latter, and the sextic unfindable on Google.  So even if there were such formulas for beyond, they'd literally be beyond any use.

Answer (score 2):

A sixth degree polynomial must have six (not necessarily distinct) roots. Depending upon the specific coefficients, it may be possible to find the roots using synthetic division.

Note that a $6$ th degree polynomial with integer coefficients does not have to have any real solutions but may have as many as six real solutions, and that any complex solutions occur in conjugate pairs of the form $x=a\pm bi$.

One may determine how many solutions of which type it might have using Descartes' Rule of Signs.

Given

\begin{equation}
f(x)=ax^6 + bx^5 + cx^4 + dx ^3 + ex^2 + fx + g 
\end{equation}

and

\begin{equation}
f(-x)=ax^6 - bx^5 + cx^4 - dx ^3 + ex^2 - fx + g 
\end{equation}

Using the actual values of the coefficients (which may be either positive or negative) count the number of sign changes (ignoring coefficients of $0$) to obtain the maximum number of positive roots. However there may be fewer than the maximum by an even number. For example if there are $3$ changes of sign in the coefficients, then their are either $3$ or $1$ positive roots.

Next, count the number of changes of sign of the coefficients of $f(-x)$. That will indicate the maximum number of negative roots. Again, there may be fewer roots than that, but only by an even amount.

Knowing the possible number of positive and negative roots one may list all the possible combinations and from that determine, for each possibility the number of pairs of complex roots, since there must be six (not necessarily distinct) roots in total.

If the coefficients are integers, then using the rational root theorem one may use synthetic division to find the rational roots if there are any. If there is some rational root $x=\frac{m}{n}$ reduced to lowest terms, then $m$ is an integer divisor of $g$ and $n$ is an integer divisor of $a$. By listing all possible factors of $a$ and $g$ one may make a list of all possible rational roots and try them one at a time using synthetic division. And if one finds, for example, that $r$ is a root, then it is the case that $x-r$ is a factor and the synthetic division result also gives the other factor as well.

In this way one may find all the rational solutions to the equation if there are any, each time reducing the degree of the remaining factor which may be investigated for its roots in the same way.